# How to get rid of decimals in a text-area/paragraph and launch regex at start?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of lines like these:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
2/9/2020 Apple $35.042 ID:2e35-s2s2-2d29-202s
1/4/2020 Banana $35.012 ID:2e45-d142-24sd-2d2s
1/17/2020 Orange $32.042 ID:2e75-s5s6-2f49-2s1s
</textarea>

<textarea id="myresults" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
</textarea>
```

The answers after should be:

```
35.04
35.01
32.04
```

I need to get rid of everything except for the price tag (get rid of everything before and after the price tag) which should be rounded to 2. 
So far every time I put this in my notepad++ I have to do regex manually in notepad++ like \bID:\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b and 
\d+/\d+/\d{4} and \b\w+\b every time I paste it I have to ctrl + h and find which wastes a lot of time. If the program can automatically replace on launch that would be awesome.

I tried to get rid of the decimals with these:

```
<script>
var text = "document.getElementById('mytext');
text.value.toFixed(2); or 
text.toFixed(2); or
text.MathRound(2); or
mytext.toFixed(2); etc
</script>
```

Comment: `I need to get rid of everything except for the price tag` ... A before and after would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks I have changed my answer, but I just simplify it on StackOverflow so people can understand it better. On my real code I actually have to keep a bit more than just the price tag but I still need to know how to get rid of the decimals in the paragraph/text-area and automatically launch regex at the start.

Comment: Ummm no, at @KaryXu, I meant a before and after on the source data (which you provide) and how you want it to be *after*. There are a bunch of prices in your source data. So what do you want the result to be?

Comment: oh gotcha, is there anyway I can start a new line without ctrl + k because it will think its a code and if I don't press ctrl + k it go in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

First [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text on newline to get an array of lines. With forEach or map you can now split again on space if the price is always the third field and then format it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lines = document.getElementById('mytext').value.split('\n')

let prices = []
lines = lines.filter(function (el) {
  if (el) { 
  let price = el.match(/\$\d+(\.\d+)?/g)[0]
  prices.push('$' + parseFloat(price.substring(1, price.length)).toFixed(2))
  };
})

let myresults = document.getElementById("myresults");
myresults.value = prices.join("\n")
```

```html
<textarea id="mytext" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
2/9/2020 Apple $35.042 ID:2e35-s2s2-2d29-202s
1/4/2020 Banana $35.012 ID:2e45-d142-24sd-2d2s
1/17/2020 Orange $32.042 ID:2e75-s5s6-2f49-2s1s
</textarea>

<textarea id="myresults" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you put /\$\d+(\.\d+)?/g? Can you get rid of bID:\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b and \d+/\d+/\d{4} in 2 lines? Because on the real code I have a lot more words but I need to simplify it on stackoverflow. If you can do it with my regex on the script it would be great.

Comment: This is basically matching if your line has anything starting with $ and getting its values. So, no matter what other words you have, as far as you have something like $<somevalue> in it, it will get its value only.

Comment: Oh yea then it doesn't work since I simplify it so it easier to understand. Can you do something like getting rid of ID:\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b and \d+/\d+/\d{4} in 2 lines so I can understand and get rid of the specific thing I want on the text-area? For example on the real code I want to get the Buy 100 Apple for 250$ each but erase the other stuff. I prefer checking the other stuff each time and replace it with blank if you know what I mean. I'm new to Javascript so.

Comment: I am confused, you have provided a sample of text and expected result. If you run code snippet, it's output is exactly what you asked for?

Comment: Yes I know but if I put 3 examples of  2/4/2020 Limit - Cover AMZN 60 $2,048.00 - EQUITIES USD f7a999d2-2482-4805-905f-6eab29b1ef2d Expired it will say my question has too much code. So I was looking for a code that check the specific thing and replace not everything except a specific thing.

Comment: if this is input 2/4/2020 Limit - Cover AMZN 60 $2,048.00 - EQUITIES USD f7a999d2-2482-4805-905f-6eab29b1ef2d Expired. What result you expect from it?

Comment: I would expect something like  mytext.replace(EQUITIES) mytext.replace(\b\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b) mytext.replace(\d+/\d+/\d{4}) mytext.replace(Filled ADD/VIEW NOTES) each line. What you did was something like search for $ and then remove if its not $. I rather have it search for this, remove this, then again.

Comment: "I need to get rid of everything except for the price tag (get rid of everything before and after the price tag) which should be rounded to 2" - Thats what you asked for?

Comment: Yes I can regex in notepad++ but everytime I paste that I have to ctrl + h and replace with blank. I don't want to find a specific thing and remove everything if its not that thing though. I want to find a specific thing and remove it if its that thing on the script.

Comment: I was looking for an answer like replace(\d+/\d+/\d{4}) blank and then replace \bID:\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b blank and then replace \b\w+\b blank then I will be left with only the price. But I don't want a code that will check if its price and get rid of everything else.